# Navigation back to LoginScreen when logout selected

Tags: c#, ios, navigation, xamarin, logout

AppDelegate

```
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    navigationController = new UINavigationController();
    navigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, true);

    loginViewController = new LoginViewController ();
    navigationController.AddChildViewController (loginViewController);

    if (validToken == true){
        Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
        Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(new DashBoardViewController(), Menu){ NavigationBarHidden = true };
        Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new SettingViewController(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
        navigationController.AddChildViewController (Menu);
    }

    window.RootViewController = navigationController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
```

Initial launch of application its check for localToken, if token exist return true else false.
if false loginViewController  will load on initial launch of application.
 After giving username and password on success authentication
run below code.

```
Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(new DashBoardViewController(), Menu){ NavigationBarHidden = true };
Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new SettingViewController(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
NavigationController.PushViewController (Menu, true);
```

In DashBoardViewController  Have LogoutButton.
// Should redirect to loginController Screen.

```
btn_Logout.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

    Console.WriteLine ("Back Pressed");
    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
//  this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController (true);
//  this.NavigationController.PopToViewController (this,true);
};
```

Its stay in same viewController which is DashBoardViewController.
Want to get back to loginviewcontroller when logout button pressed.

@All 
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are trying to navigate back in the NavigationController that doesn't have LoginViewController in the stack of viewControllers. So in you AppDelegate add the next code

```
public void GoToLoginScreen()
{
    navigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
}
```

And in `btn_Logout.TouchUpInside` event

```
btn_Logout.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Back Pressed");
    (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).GoToLoginScreen();
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  it worked... Little correction in that navigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);